# Md-Autocomplete: How to update autocomplete textbox value based on the selection from dropdown?

Tags: angularjs, angular-material, md-autocomplete

I am able to achieve that by manually updating the model value which is bind to md-search-text, but that will trigger the autocomplete request again.
Any inputs?

Comment: Can you give a link to codepen or JSBin with your code in it ??

Comment: I ended up creating my own autocomplete..